# How can I limit a draggable child with right and bottom value of parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a draggable map. I found how to limit a draggable child for left and top sides but couldn't figure out how to make same thing for right and bottom sides.

How can I limit a draggble child with right and bottom value of parent?

```
     var uright = ui.position.left + 960;  /* 960 is map height*/
     var pright = parentPos.left + 700;    /* 500 is container height*/

      if (ui.position.top > parentPos.top) {
     ui.position.top = parentPos.top; // works fine
      }
       if (ui.position.left > parentPos.left) {
     ui.position.left= parentPos.left; // works fine
      }
    if (uright > pright) {
        uright = pright; // that doesnt work
      }
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQtCY/148/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `getBoundingClientRect` method instead of using `position` method.The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns a text rectangle object that encloses a group of text rectangles.

```
rectObject = object.getBoundingClientRect();
```

> The returned value is a TextRectangle object which is the union of the
>   rectangles returned by getClientRects() for the element, i.e., the CSS
>   border-boxes associated with the element.
>
> The returned value is a TextRectangle object, which contains read-only
>   left, top, right and bottom properties describing the border-box in
>   pixels. top and left are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

You can then get `top,left,right,bottom` values of the element i.e. `rectObject.right,rectObject.top,rectObject.bottom,`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Alternatively, why don't you try `containment` option in jquery draggable.
Link : http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

Comment: is it possible to choose a starting position (example: middle of the map) in containment ?

Comment: You can use helper option for that in draggable. Explore the api of draggable.There are many great options for use!